# Layer 3 Switching in Packet Tracer not working

Tags: vlan, switching, layer3, packet-tracer

I am studying for ICND1 through CBTNuggets,

I recently watched videos on how to interact between different vlans using separate interfaces, sub-interfaces and Layer 3 Switching.

The first two worked fine for me, but the Layer 3 Switching is not working when i am pinging PC in one VLAN to the PC in other VLAN.

Suppose PC A is connected to Fa0/1 of Switcher and PC B is connected to Fa0/2 of Switcher.

Here is what I did,

I went to Switcher CLI,
Went to Global Configuration mode,

created two vlans using commands,

```
# vlan 10
# vlan 20
```

Now I moved `fa0/0` port to `vlan 10` and `fa0/1` port to `vlan 20`

I assigned IP addresses to PCs,

PC A (fa0/1):

```
10.1.1.100
```

Default Gateway: `10.1.1.1`
Subnet Mask: `255.255.255.0`

PC B (fa0/2):

```
10.1.2.100
```

Subnet Mask: `255.255.255.0`
Default Gateway: `10.1.2.1`

Now i went to the CLi of switcher and did this in Global mode,

```
# interface vlan 10
# ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
# no shutdown
# exit
# interface vlan 20
# ip address 10.1.2.1 255.255.255.0
# no shutdown
# exit
```

Both vlans `10` and `20` are up and running and all the ports are up too, but I couldn't be able to ping `PC B` from `PC A`.

This is exactly what the guy did in the video and he managed to ping.

What did i miss ?

P.S: I also tried to erase arp tables but still couldn't be able to ping.

Comment: Please post the switch config.

Comment: I am guessing it is a typo, but generally there is no Fa0/0.  Did you mean that you moved Fa0/1 to VLAN 10 and Fa0/2 to VLAN 20?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the switch, your IP for interface vlan 20 is wrong.

```
# interface vlan 20
# ip address 10.1.2.1 255.255.255.0
# no shutdown
```

Then make sure you have `ip routing` on.

Also the gateway for PC A should be `10.1.1.1` while the gateway for PC B should be `10.1.2.1`. The subnet mask should be `255.255.255.0` not the gateway.

Once fixed, make sure you can ping the gateway of each PC from the respective PCs as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to you, PC'B' is on fa0/2. This means that PC'B' is on VLAN 1 by default.
And PC'A' is in VLAN 20.

That is the mistake i guess

Comment: This question already has an [accepted answer](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/9807/775); that was the solution to the problem